# java - cannot find symbol

Tags: java

If i have this in my main method: `PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));`

and this in another method: `output.println(currentLine);`

and `import java.io.*;` obviously,

does anyone know why I am getting

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable output
location: class TestClass
        output.println(currentLine);
```

Comment: Show us the code as it is in the file, not as a narrative please.

Comment: It is complaining about the symbol `symbol`. Where are you using that?  IMHO, I would use an IDE to help you find and auto-fix this issue.

Comment: The variable output is out of scope. Define it as an instance variable not in main

Comment: add your complete code here. Seems like you have a scope issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler tells you that the name (symbol) `output` is not defined in the scope (and enclosing scopes) where you want to use it.  Based on the definition

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
```

it seems you define `output` in the `main()` function, but want to use it in a class `TestClass`, which is not valid as `output` is only defined within `main()`

Assuming `main()` is defined within `TestClass` you could define `output` in the class, then assign its value in `main()` and use it within the class later:

```
public class TestClass {
  PrintWriter output;
  public void write(String currentLine) {
    output.println(currentLine);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass tc = new TestClass();
    tc.output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
    tc.write("Sometext");
  }
}
```

Comment: no i want to use it in the method called reverse, which is part of the TestClass

Comment: My code is an example: substitute `write()` with `reverse()` in `TestClass` and you're good to go: main idea is that 1) you define `output` in the class where you want to use it; 2) you assign its value in `main()` (or whatever other function) where you know the parameters to create the object with; 3) call `reverse()` after the value of `output` has been set: you can use `output`, becuase it is a) in scope and b) has the proper value

Comment: @Attila - you can't initialize a non static class member from within a static method.